# ID is 'undefined' using .each()

Tags: jquery

Why is this alerting 'undefined' instead of the link id's? I do get 'undefined' 5 times so I know it's looping over them correctly, but it's not displaying the name like 'Cripple', etc.

```
$(function () {
    $("#divPlayerActions").children("a").each(function () {
       var e = $(this);
       alert(e.id);      // undefined ?
    });
}
```

```
<div id="divPlayerActions" class="col-md-6 text-center">
   <a href="#" class="action" data-cd="0" data-cast="0" id='Cripple'> <img src="/Content/cripple.png" /> </a>
   <a href="#" class="action" data-cd="0" data-cast="0" id='GroundSlam'> <img src="/Content/ground_slam.png" /> </a>
   <a href="#" class="action" data-cd="0" data-cast="0" id='HealingStar'> <img src="/Content/healing_star.png" /> </a>
   <a href="#" class="action" data-cd="0" data-cast="0" id='LighteningStrike'> <img src="/Content/lightening_strike.png" /> </a>
   <a href="#" class="action" data-cd="0" data-cast="0" id='PoisonBite'> <img src="/Content/poison_bite.png" /> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You're confusing jQuery and the DOM. A jQuery object has no `id` property, but a DOM Element does. Do `this.id` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to revoke the native JS DOM Element Object out of the jQuery Object:

```
alert( e[0].id );
```

or simply do

```
alert( this.id );
```

or use jQuery:

```
alert( e.prop("id") ); /*    this one */
alert( e.get(0).id; ); /* or this one */
alert( e.attr("id") ); /* or this one */
```

or pass the `this` target identifier trough the jQuery `.each(index, element)` argument:

```
$("#divPlayerActions").children("a").each(function (i, e) {
    alert(e.id); // Cripple // GroundSlam // HealingStar .....
});
```

Comment: Why does it work like that? In another place I have the following and it works.  $(".action").click(function (e) { alert($(this).id); }

Comment: @user441521 Can you please provide an example (test-case) where that happens so I can see? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get this value with jQuery just grab it as an attribute:

```
e.attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to retrieve element ID

```
   $(function () {
        $("#divPlayerActions").children("a").each(function () {
           var e = $(this);
           alert( e.prop("id"));  
        });
    }
```